# Detect data spikes (loops) in MySQL database and ignore these

Tags: mysql

i must create some statistics out of a WWW access log database, but i found out that there are some redirect loops after a login if the user has disabled cookies. So there are 10-1000 mostly identical rows like the following:

```
...
/login?redirect=/app - 200 - 123.123.123.123 - 2014-01-01 10:00:00
/app                 - 403 - 123.123.123.123 - 2014-01-01 10:00:00
/login?redirect=/app - 200 - 123.123.123.123 - 2014-01-01 10:00:00
/app                 - 403 - 123.123.123.123 - 2014-01-01 10:00:01
...
```

Is there a way to detect unusal count grouped by the ip/url in an interval? I think i need to select all counts for each minute an detect a spike and ignore that... Does anyone had the same difficulties?

Comment: Do you have the different fields of the access log available as different columns?

Comment: This kind of query is very easy with window functions -- specifically `lag` and `lead`, but I don't think MySQL has these.

Comment: @Colin'tHart Yes of course, everything is in it's own column, hence the "-". The tables contains way more columns but these are not relevant for my problem...

Comment: @Constantin So how would you define a "spike", more than N hits in the same minute by the same user, on the same URL, with a particular code, all of them?

Comment: @jynus Basically there are some redirect loops due to the fact that some users block cookies... so a typical request i have is something like: normal html site with a link to a dynamic application which required a login (the login may be a default user auto login), so a click on the application link redirects to the login, because the user isn't logged in yet, the login detects if the user is a default user and may login the user as a default user and redirect back to the dynamic application, but if cookies are blocked. this redirect loops forever if the user does not know whats going on

Comment: @jynus The pattern is quite simple... check if a given ip has a pattern of a login with a redirect to the destination and so on...

Comment: If ignore means block you could use something like fail2ban. Or look at refer to determine if its already redirected (maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Acoording to your pattern, you could do something like this (change your column names and url pattern accordingly):

```
mysql> SET @max_redirects := 10;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*) as `# redirects`, ip, min(url) as url, 
              time_event - INTERVAL SECOND(time_event) SECOND AS minute 
       FROM log WHERE url like '/login?redirect=%' 
       GROUP BY ip, minute 
       HAVING `# redirects` > @max_redirects;
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
| # redirects | ip              | url                  | minute              |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
|          53 | 1.1.1.1         | /login?redirect=/    | 2014-08-05 08:03:00 |
|          21 | 1.1.1.1         | /login?redirect=/    | 2014-08-05 08:05:00 |
|         128 | 123.123.123.123 | /login?redirect=/app | 2014-01-01 10:00:00 |
+-------------+-----------------+----------------------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Expect this to be slow on a tall table, so add an index on your timestamp column and filter by date to avoid huge sorts.

Comment: Thanks, i think that gets me working... but it is, as you said, pretty slow, even with all nesessary indexes

Comment: @Constantin It can be easily improved, but you would need a couple of changes in structure, that I do not know if you can do or if the original table supports it.

Comment: The table only has the following columns: id,e_url,e_full_url,e_time,e_method,e_status,e_length,e_referer,e_ip,e_country,e_city,ua_name,ua_version,ua_full,os_name,os_version,os_family,e_ignore,e_internal. The database is kind of old but could or should be replaced if necessary. Old data could be imported. (e_url is varchar(254) to be indexed, e_full_url contains the full url with query string)

Comment: Maybe another info: each month is stored in an own table. each tables has 5-6m rows, trending up. bots and some files(js,css,jpg,png,ico) already filtered out, because we do not need these information in the database.